# Are the images of a continuous function necessarily connected?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to understand this Theorem from Ross' Elementary Analysis:

"Consider metric spaces $(S,d), (S*,d*)$, and let $f: S \to S*$ be continuous. If $E$ is a connected subset of $S$, then $f(E)$ is a connected subset of $S*$."

I cannot think of an example of a continuous function whose images are disconnected. But this must be possible or this theorem would not make sense. Could someone provide an example for me so I can understand this better?

Is this because a function is continuous if it is continuous **at every point in its domain** and so the only time you have disconnected images is if the domain is disconnected?

Comment: I mean, the theorem says "yes."

Comment: The image of a connected space under a continuous map is again connected.  If you delete either "continuous" or the first "connected" then it may be false.

Comment: Well, if $S=S^*$ and $f$ is the identity map, then if $E\subset S$ is not connected, then $f(E)=E$ is not connected.

Comment: Saying "have disconnected images" as if being connected is a property of individual points in not really the right way to think about these things. But if you want to say that a continuous function, when restricted to a connected set (which could be the whole domain if the domain is connected), has a connected image, then yes, _that is precisely what the cited theorem is saying_.

Comment: @randall Thank you very much! This is a time where the obvious was too close for me to see. I understand now.

Comment: @marc Thank you for the helpful rephrasing. It really cleared up my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I cannot think of an example of a continuous function whose images are disconnected. But this must be possible or this theorem would not make sense.

Consider $f : [0, 1] \cup [2, 3] \to [0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$ defined by $f(x) = x$. Then $f([0, 1] \cup [2, 3]) = [0, 1] \cup [2, 3]$ is disconnected. And clearly $f$ is continuous.

Is the problem that you don't understand what the theorem is saying or that you don't understand the proof of the theorem?

Comment: There are some parts of the proof that I don't understand yet but figured that should go in a separate question. In regards to this question, I am simply by habit used to thinking of the domain as, for example, all of R. So if I saw the graph of your example, I would immediately think, "Oh, that's not continuous", rather than stopping to consider a more restricted domain, and recognizing that ON THE GIVEN DOMAIN, this f(x)= x is indeed continuous. Your example really helped me understand the whole theorem better and clear up my thinking. Thank you!

Comment: @m4th3m4t1cs You're welcome! I am glad that I was able to help you in this way. A large part of analysis (and topology) is coming up with counterintuitive counterexamples which disprove things one would like to be true, so I advise that you view your own intuition with a healthy dose of skepticism (at least starting out).

Comment: Actually, $f(x)=x$ is continuous on **any** subset of $\Bbb R$. There is nothing peculiar about $[0,1]\cup[2,3]$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider, for instance,$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\dfrac x{|x|}.\end{array}$$Then $f$ is continuous, but its image is $\{1,-1\}$, which is disconnected.

Comment: Thank you for the example. This makes sense. And indeed the domain is disconnected, which exactly proves the point.